# How do you discover the AWS Cloudformation stackname on an EC2 Instance to use with cfn-init commands

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

We've got some Windows EC2 Instances deployed using Cloudformation that are configured using [cfn-init](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-init.html) scripts.

In order to update components on the instances later on, we need to re-run some of the [Cloudformation::Init configsets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-init.html#aws-resource-init-configsets) using the cfn-init helper scripts and one of the required parameters, *--stack*, is the stack name. I was expecting this value would be dynamically available via the [EC2 Instance Metadata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html) as a single call but I have not been able to find it.

I am posting a workaround script but I'm still wondering if there is a simpler, robust way that I am missing.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to define cfn-hup in your cloudformation template so that it lays down the files with variables you need:

*from docs*

```yaml
...
  LaunchConfig:
    Type: "AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration"
    Metadata:
      QBVersion: !Ref paramQBVersion
      AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
...
            /etc/cfn/hooks.d/cfn-auto-reloader.conf:
              content: !Sub |
                [cfn-auto-reloader-hook]
                triggers=post.update
                path=Resources.LaunchConfig.Metadata.AWS::CloudFormation::Init
                action=/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource LaunchConfig --configsets wordpress_install --region ${AWS::Region}
                runas=root
              mode: "000400"
              owner: "root"
              group: "root"
...
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-hup.html

Comment: I'm already using cfn-hup in this fashion to automatically run a configset automatically on an application version number change in the Metadata and that works well.

My scenario is a bit different where I want to conditionally run a specific configset from either the command line interactively or via an SSM Run Command.

Comment: gotcha. ' I was expecting this value would be dynamically available via the EC2 Instance Metadata ' so you can do this if you enable "tags on metadata" feature on your instances. cloudformation automatically applies a few reserved tags when launching resources, one of them is `aws:cloudformation:stack-name`... or parsing you're cfn-hup.conf

Comment: Accessing the stack-name tag is is a great idea though - thanks. I will need to enable InstanceMetadataTags as I don't have that on at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Since the initial cfn-init command included in the User Data script includes the [${AWS::StackName} Psuedo parameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/pseudo-parameter-reference.html#cfn-pseudo-param-stackname) we can parse this script to extract it. The following PowerShell script illustrates the technique and a similar bash script could be used on Linux instances:

```
function Get-CfnInitStackName {
    [string]$token = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{"X-aws-ec2-metadata-token-ttl-seconds" = "21600"} -Method PUT -Uri http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token
    $userDataScript = (Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{"X-aws-ec2-metadata-token" = $token} -Method GET -Uri http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data).script
    # Exact regex would be determined by your command usage in the UserData element of your Cloudformation template
    if ($userDataScript -match 'cfn-init.+ --stack (?<stackName>\S+) --resource') {
        $stackName = $Matches.stackName
    } else {
        throw "Stack name not found within user data script" + [System.Environment]::NewLine + $userDataScript
    }

    $stackName
}

function Invoke-CfnInitConfigset([string]$ConfigSet = 'deploy_full') {
    $stackName = Get-CfnInitStackName
    cfn-init --verbose --stack $stackName --resource Instance --region ap-southeast-2 --configsets $ConfigSet
    # TODO: Handle result code and disploy cfn-init.log output
}
```

Note I considered using the [aws cloudformation describe-stack-resources](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/cloudformation/describe-stack-resources.html) call providing the ec2 instance-id from metadata as the `--physical-resource-id` parmeter. This does work but is an extra dependency on an external service acall and would require the IAM Instance Profile permissions to be extended.